# How can I share a folder between Ubuntu 13.10 as host OS and Windows 8.1 as guest in VirtualBox?

Tags: shared-folders

I installed Windows 8.1 Pro as guest OS in VirtualBox. I want to share a folder between Ubuntu 13.10 as my host OS and guest OS for file transfer between them. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install the "guest OS additions" (start the guest OS and have look in the menus), then close down the guest OS and look through the "Settings" of Virtualbox itself, there is a section for sharer folders.

Answer (score 0):

Shared folders use a Linux folder as a network drive.  It can be selected as one way to host or from host, or Bi-Directionally.  To do this from the Drive manager:

1. Mouse right click the Machine
2. Settings
3. Shared Folder
4. Mouse click the Folder with a tiny + sign on it

At which point you will then pick a spot outside a folder that requires root to access.  A folder in you /home is suffice.  At which point you should select full access and auto-mount.  However, there is a trick for it to be enabled.

In order to get those Guest additions, you must first add the package addon from the USC or Terminal using `sudo apt-get install dkms`  from there you can run virtualbox straight from the terminal by typing `sudo virtualbox`.  At which point you will then start the machine.  Let it boot, after that being said and done you will then go to your VM menu and select devices, Insert Guest additions Disk img....  At this point you will then be prompted with a "what to do" box in your Guest OS.  At which point you will install and reboot your Guest OS.